# How to apply a Tailwind transition on dynamically generated class in React?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have simple classes that are generated dynamically using state and ternary operations.

```
    const [isLarge, setIsLarge] = useState(true);
```

returns

```
    <div
      className={`w-5 h-5 flex flex-col  justify-around ${ isLarge ? `items-end` : `items-start`} cursor-pointer`}
      onClick={() => setIsLarge((prev) => !prev)}
    />
```

How do I make tailwind know when the class has changed so that i can apply transitions like `ease-in` and `duration`?

Comment: A quick google search showed me this: https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode

Answer (score 0):

Transition can be applied only on numbers. You can find the full list of compatible properties [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties)